# Как правильно подключить CSS к представлению ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

Создал пустое приложение ASP.NET Core. Самостоятельно пытаюсь реализовать патерн MVC и для представления(Мастер-страницы), расположенного в папке Views/Shared пытаюсь применить CSS стиль, который расположен в отдельной папке Styles, находящейся в корне проекта.

Пытаюсь в представлении подключить стиль к странице следующим образом:

```
<link type="text/css" href="~/Styles/MainStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Но ничего не работает

Искал в интернете, пытался подключить разными способами - все тщетно!
Вроде делов-то, подключить css к cshtml страницы, а мучений куча

Структура проекта выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну почти всё сделали, осталось только положить (руками или через bundleconfig.json) копию файла в wwwroot/Styles/MainStyle.css. Проверка очень проста: вы сейчас открываете в браузере https://localhost:34567/Styles/MainStle.css и у вас выдаёт 404, а когда положите копию файла - то отдаст его содержимое. Проверьте только что для файла в папке wwwroot установлен build action = content

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У вас нет общего понимания, как работает веб-сервер под asp.net core.

Мысленно разделите все файлы на две большие кучки: статические файлы, которые отдаются веб-сервером "как есть" (картинки разных расширений, текстовые файлы, файлы стилей и т.п.) и файлы, которые являются программным кодом (cshtml, cs)

В asp.net core есть по поводу статических файлов простая договорённость, что все они должны лежать в папке wwwroot - туда складывают ico, css, js, jpeg, png, txt, tiff, woff2 и тому подобные файлы.

То, то вы создали в проекте папку Styles - это ничего не говорит веб-серверу о том, что этот файл должен показываться как статический. Он вообще никуда не пойдёт по умолчанию, даже не "сбилдится" (условно), если вы не укажете build action = сomplice, resources или что там ещё. Да и вообще build action по отношению к статике мало осмысленны, ну да ладно.

Тот знак ~ с которого начинается href="~/Styles/MainStyle.css" означает корневую папку, но не корневую папку вашего проекта, а корневую папку вебсервера! А это и есть папка wwwroot.

Поэтому вам нужно сделать следующее. Настроить bunleconfig.json который будет по нажатию вами кнопки build, run или publish копировать ваши стили в папку wwwroot (возможно и при этом минифицируя):

```
// Configure bundling and minification for the project.
// More info at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=808241
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site_admin.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "Areas/Admin/Styles/*.css"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site_admin.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site_admin.css"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "Styles/*.css"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  }
]
```

Либо нужно будет указать, что папка Styles является папкой на веб-сервере. Я правда смутно уже помню, как я это делал в asp.net классическом, а в mvc core вообще ни разу такого не делал, так что можете поделить этот совет на два и использовать гарантированные решения.

Вместо майкрософтовского bunleconfig.json можете использовать любые другие системы сборки - gulp, grunt. Но лучше попробуйте сначала расковырять штатный из коробки способ, а потом уже исследовать менее нативные для платформы.

Updated. Ой, ещё вспомнил! Так часто стал писать вебсервисы, что забыл, что статику ещё нужно включить в startup.cs:

```
        app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Это как раз говорит вашему приложению, что у вас не только код в приложении, но ещё и статические файлы в wwwroot находятся.

Можете кликнуть по этому методу, посмотреть как настраивается мидлварь StaticFileMiddleware и какие у неё есть параметры.

Ссылки по теме:

- [Бандлинг и минификация в asp.net core](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/13.6.php)
- [Введение в бандлы и минификацию](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc/15.1.php) - классический mvc